# Connection to MSSQL timed out

Tags: linux, networking, sql-server, ms-sql, kubernetes

from a Kubernetes Linux pod, i am trying to establish a MSSQL connection to a Windows Server on Port 1433. I have full admin access to all the machines.
I already made sure that the SQL Server instance is working. I can successfully establish a connection from another (windows) client. But not from the pod.
I used the exact same connection data (standard instance). 
The error is "connection timed out".

Because i found this awkward, I monitored the network packets on the SQL Server via wireshark. And hurray - there are arriving the correct packets on 1433. But the sql server is never sending any response packets.

There is something not correctly configured. But I dont know what. Any suggestions?

Greetings, xola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple. Since the Database Server has no route where to send out the packages (because the source IP of the packets is the IP of the Kubernetes Pod, which is on another network), I had to add the route back manually. As Gateway for the whole IP range I chose the Kubernetes server.
Now working correctly.